# Why does Newtonsoft JsonConvert not deserialize Json array fields?

Tags: c#, arrays, json, json.net, deserialization

I am fetching a Json object which has a Details field that is an array of Detail objects, for example:

```
"details":"[{\"field_id\":\"1142488407\",\"response\":\"256\",\"field_type\":\"text\"},{\"field_id\":\"72403497\",\"response\":\"\",\"field_type\":\"text\"},{\"field_id\":\"845605582\",\"response\":\"Michael\",\"field_type\":\"text\"},{\"field_id\":\"987024660\",\"response\":\"157\",\"field_type\":\"dropdown\"}]"
```

The model I have for the Details field is:

```
[JsonProperty("details")]
public List<LogDetailModel> DetailModels { get; set; }
```

And the Detail object model is:

```
[JsonProperty("field_id")]
public string EditedFieldId { get; set; }

[JsonProperty("response")]
public string Response { get; set; }

[JsonProperty("field_type")]
public string FieldType { get; set; }
```

However, when I try to deserialize the results (an array of my base model), I get the following:

> JsonSerializationException: Error converting value "[{"field_id":"1142488407","response":"256","field_type":"text"},{"field_id":"72403497","response":"","field_type":"text"},{"field_id":"845605582","response":"Michael","field_type":"text"},{"field_id":"987024660","response":"157","field_type":"dropdown"}]" to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[KolHalev.Business.Breeze.Models.LogDetailModel]'. Path '[0].details', line 1, position 423.

And if I instead fetch that field as a string, and then deserialize thusly:

```
[JsonProperty("details")]
public string Details { get; set; }
public List<LogDetailModel> DetailModels { get { return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<LogDetailModel>>(Details); }  }
```

This works fine.  What am I missing?

Comment: `"details":"[{...}]"`: the `details` field's type is string. `"details":[{...}]`: the `details` field's type is collection.

Comment: @PeterCsala  -that makes sense!  Addled brain didn't recognize.  Wil you submit as answer so I can give you credit?

Comment: Yepp, thanks mate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you could not deserialize it directly is because your json and your data model has a mismatch.

```json
"details":"[{\"field_id\":\"1142488407\",\"response\":\"256\",\"field_type\":\"text\"},..]"
```

- In this case your `details` data type is string
- So, you can NOT parse it directly as a collection of objects

if your json would look like this:

```json
"details":[{\"field_id\":\"1142488407\",\"response\":\"256\",\"field_type\":\"text\"},..]
```

- the the data type of the `details` field would be a collection

---

So, the very reason why did your second approach worked is because you have first deserialized the `details` then you deserialized the json array.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Details details = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Details>(json);

     //Or more flexible
    //Detail details = new Details
    //{
    //  DetailsString = (string)JObject.Parse(json)["details"]
    //};
```

classes

```
public class Details
{
    [JsonProperty("details")]
    public string DetailsString { get; set; }
    public List<LogDetailModel> DetailModels { get { return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<LogDetailModel>>(DetailsString); } }
}

public class LogDetailModel
{
    [JsonProperty("field_id")]
    public string EditedFieldId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("response")]
    public string Response { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("field_type")]
    public string FieldType { get; set; }
}
```